# Encapsulate fields in div

Tags: entities

I need to encapsulate in Drupal 7 some fields intro a div and other fields in another div. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way the html is genereated for a field by overwriting the apropriate theme method.

Tho find the method you can use the [theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer). After enabling the module you can click on the appropriate field to see the theme methods which are important for you.

Have a lookg at the [themeing giude](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme) if this is all new for you.

Comment: All I see is theme_field() function. Yet, how do I wrap into divs?

Comment: In your custom function first call theme_field. Then do an if() to filter your fields (check what is passed in in the $variables array) and wrap the output into an additional <div>.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the [Field Group](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) module.  This allows you to add a "group" of fields from the *Manage fields* screen in the same way that you add fields.

By choosing "Fieldset" as the type of the group, you can add only a div.  Field Group is primarily designed to allow you to add different kinds of tab groups, but you can also use it to add just a custom div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use theme suggestions : 
field--[type|name[--content-type]|content-type].tpl.php

See http://drupal.org/node/1089656